# One Page or Post, n Slugs

Tags: slug, routing

What would be the best option for serving up a page for any one of many slugs. Suppose I have the following:

- example.com/the-broken-slug
- example.com/thebrokenslug
- example.com/broken-slug
- example.com/brokenslug

And I would like all of those to deliver up my page having the title "Broken Slug." My first impulse was to look for a plugin that would permit me to define custom routes and declare which posts or pages should be mapped.

Does anybody know of a tested and trustworthy solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this plugin -> http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/